# Statistics binomials

Tags: probability, statistics

1. A recent medical survey reported that 45% of the respondents to a poll on patient 
   care felt that doctors usually explain things well to their patients. Assuming that the 
   poll reflects the feelings of all patients toward their doctors, find the probability that 
   for 12 patients selected at random: 
   (a) Four of more agree with the statement. 
   (b) No more than 8 do not agree with the statement.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Is there a way to use binomcdf on your calculator or do you have to individually do each binompdf for part a and then add them all together. For example binompdf(12,0.45,4)+binompdf(12,0.45,5)+etc. all the way up to 12

Comment: Yeah, my calculator will do the c.d.f for me.  How about yours?

Comment: Even if it doesn't, though, your answer suggests that you know how to calculate the answer, if only in a slightly more tedious fashion. Why don't you post an addendum to your question with your work and answer and then we can see what you did?

Comment: How would you put it in your calculator binomcdf(12,0.45,_?_).

Comment: I am not quite sure how to work it all out... we never learned that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is [binomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $p=0.45$ and $n=12$ and $$\mathrm{Pr}[m \text{ out of } n \text{ felt doctors explain well}]=\binom{m}{n}p^m (1-p)^{n-m}.$$  There's nothing wrong with computing the probability the way you suggest:

1. Four or more patients agree: $$\sum_{m=4}^{12} \mathrm{Pr}[m \text{ out of } 12 \text{ felt doctors explain well}].$$
2. No more than 8 do not agree with the statement: this is the same as no fewer than $12-8=4$ agree with the statement (so this is the same question as 1.).

An alternative way to compute it is $$1-\sum_{m=0}^{3} \mathrm{Pr}[m \text{ out of } 12]$$ which is slightly more efficient.

[Computer algebra systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) can be handy for inputting sums like this.  For example, in [R](http://www.r-project.org/) we use

```
sum(dbinom(4:12,12,0.45))
```

which returns the probability $\approx 0.8655319$.  And we can double-check the second claim with

```
1-sum(dbinom(0:3,12,0.45))
```

which also returns $\approx 0.8655319$.